# How to change gunicorn worker from the default worker of 'sync' to 'eventlet' on Azure App Services?

Tags: flask, gunicorn, flask-socketio

I was trying to use the flask-socketio to send and receive data from a python/flask web app deployed on Azure Web Services (Linux/B1), but came into issues when the client started to send data using the fetch(POST) function.

It is my suspicion that the fact gunicorn is using the default 'sync', instead of 'eventlet' or 'gevent' as required for asynchronous support on flask-socketio is the cause of the issues. So I added GUNICORN_CMD_ARGS to Azure app settings with value of "--workers=4 --worker-class=eventlet app:app", and restarted the app several times, only to find gunicorn still getting started with the 'sync' worker every time.

Can I anyone let me know how I can actually change the gunicorn worker from 'sync' to 'eventlet' here?

Comment: what version of gunicorn you use?